# VSCodeのターミナル（bash）でPythonの対話モードを実行した際、補完などができない

Tags: python, python3, vscode

お世話になっております。

VSCodeのターミナル（bash）でPythonの対話モードを実行したとき、`Tab`キーで補完したり、`↑`キーでコマンド履歴を参照したいのですが、どうすればよいのか分からず困っております。

●環境
- OS: Windows7 64bit
- Python: 3.6.2
- VSCode: 1.27.1

※ターミナルをbashから変えずに解決したいです。

[image: 現在の実行画面。Tabで補完が効かない。]

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyreadline をインストールしてみてください。

```
pip install pyreadline
```